# How to change URL within GWT app

Tags: gwt

I'm working with a gwt multipage project which I used these code to switch between html pages, for this case switching from index.html to signup.html page:

```
public static native void fireChangePage(String url)/*-{
        $wnd.location.href = url;
}-*/;

public void goToSignUpPage(boolean isDeployed) {
  String url = (isDeployed == true ? "signup.html" : "signup.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997");
        fireChangePage(url);
}
```

I'm getting error 404 when `fireChangePage` is called from the EntryPoint for the index.html.
Manually changing the url on the browser say: index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 to signup.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 works, so I can say that the problem is with the native function `fireChangePage`.

What could be the problem with the native function? Or is there a better approach than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's GWT project, you should switch between places (using PlaceController) instead of switching between HTML pages . Anyway, if you have to do so, I'd recommend to use `com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location` class instead (it's provided by framework and works fine).

Comment: I did use Window.Location.replace(url) however it also returns error 404. Actually, what works for my is to user HTML object and put the link with <a href="the_url"> which works, however using this approach create a "hyperlink" (the color blue one) which does not really look good with my gwt app.

Comment: So when the location is changed (by Window.Location), and you see 404 error code in your browser, when you hit "enter" (ask browser to try again), also 404 error appears? (you said that if you specify it manually, you can see the right page - so when you hit enter it's  the same as when you specify it manually). I am pretty sure that it's something with your URL - I've used Window.Location many times and every single one it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding slash to the path of the document, i.e. `/signup.html`.